# What interaction did the Buddha have with his family after leaving?

Tags: the-buddha

I know he did some teaching with his mother in the heaven realms but what other incidents are mentioned in the cannon?

Answer (score 6):

Apart from Dhammadhatu's answer regarding the Buddha's [son Rahula becoming a monk](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/24lbud.htm), there are also other interactions with his family, like the founding of the order of nuns due to the insistence of his aunt and [foster mother, Maha Pajapati Gotami, who became the first nun](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/2_23lbud.htm).

Also, [his wife, Yasodhara later became a nun](http://buddhajourney.net/siddharta-gautama-and-yasodhara/) and [his half-sister Sundari Nanda also became a nun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanda_(Buddhist_nun)).

And, not to forget one of the Buddha's most well known disciples and personal attendant, [Ven. Ananda who is also his cousin](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/disciples09.htm).

While his father, King Suddhodana did not become a monk, he too had some interaction with the Buddha, when his grandson Rahula became a monk, leading to the [new rule being created](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/24lbud.htm), that nobody would be ordained without their parents' permission.

> When King Suddhodana heard that his beloved grandson had become a monk
>   he was deeply grieved. The king said, "When you left home it made me
>   sad. When Nanda left home my heart ached. I concentrated my love on my
>   grandson and again the one I love has left me. Please do not ordain
>   anyone without their parent's permission." To this the Buddha agreed
>   and never ordained anybody after that without their parents'
>   permission.

Answer (score 3):

He taught his son Rahula non-harming at 7 years old & when older meditation & full enlightenment.

The teachings to his son are here: [Advice to Rāhula: Four Discourses of the Buddha](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh033_Nyanaponika_Adivce-To-Rahula--Four-Discourses.html).

These teachings basically make up the entirely of the Dhamma.